# Java - replace regex in file

Tags: java, regex, file

In java, I have a file where I need to replace text that matches a regex with something that depends on the text matched (it's an assembly file, and I have to replace a method name by its address, stored in a tabular).

Is there a better way to do this than load it to a string, replace in it, and write it again in the file ? I couldn't find anything that can work 'directly' in the file.

Thanks for help,

Comment: What do you mean by "work directly in the file"?

Comment: I mean that I don't need to load it to a String, perform my replacements in that String and write it again, but rather modify the File object where it matches.

Comment: Why do you think it is bad to load the file as text, change it and write it back to a file? You have text, so you don't want to work on low level bytes. A random access file wouldn't help much. You cannot expect that you replace the matches with content of exactly the same byte length.

Comment: If the file is too big to fit into memory you can read it line by line, processing each line individually.

Comment: Ok I see your point. Actually the file could be quite big and I don't perform replacements in all of it, but only on part of it, so I thought it would be a waste of time to load everything.